# 1 vertex pulls out and ignores subdivide / smoothing

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface, wireframe

Sometimes i have a vertex that isn't cooperating with subdivision and smoothing.

In image u will see 1 vertex ignoring the smoothing process.

[image]

Whenever i have these it creates creases and is a pain to fix. The fix is to dissolve and create a new vertex.

Is there a solution to this and/or how can i prevent this?

Can individual vertices have there own settings and might that be the issue? Is it somehow locked on that position?

Comment: maybe you have flipped normals?

Comment: wow, that did it. Didn't know that was a thing. tx.

Comment: Fixed! Normals were flipped for some faces in that corner.